# Running Test Cases Separately Nunit Console Runner

Tags: nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I am developing tests using Nunit3 and have several test cases for one method. I want to **run test cases separately** using **Nunit console runner**. How can I achieve this?

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Something like this runs all the test cases in the end.

```
nunit3-console.exe --test=DivideTest(12,3,4) path/to/your/test.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming the test case provided what I was looking for as a workaround:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4 TestName="foo"))]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}

nunit3-console.exe --test=foo path/to/your/test.dll
```